# What's the equivalent of `rs.slaveOk()` for config file in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

I have set up my MongoDB on local machine with *replicaSet*, and I have this error:

> An error occurred while loading navigation: 'not master and
> slaveOk=false': It is recommended to change your read preference in
> the connection dialog to Primary Preferred or Secondary Preferred or
> provide a replica set name for a full topology connection.

If I don't exec this command on secondary servers,

```
rs.slaveOk()
```

After using the command, the problem is solved, but only temporarily. After restarting the servers, the above error pops up again, I again have to stop it using the command.

How can I somehow define the `slaveOk` in a config file, so that I don't have to allow `slaveOk` each time I start the server?

Comment: Because you are connecting to secondary specifically, and it is trying to stop you unintentionally making changes to secondary which will not be replicated to any other node.

Comment: So, how am i supposed to do it ?? (i am using on nodejs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection string should look something like this:

```
mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017,mongodb1.example.com:27017,mongodb2.example.com:27017/?replicaSet=myRepl
```

If you are connecting from shell

```
mongo "mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017,mongodb1.example.com:27017,mongodb2.example.com:27017/?replicaSet=myRepl"
```

OR

```
mongo --host myRepl/mongodb0.example.com.local:27017,mongodb1.example.com.local:27017,mongodb2.example.com.local:27017
```

Where `myRepl` is the replica set name, `mongodbX.example.com.local:27017` are your nodes.